# Rails 5: Object's parent ID being lost between the new action and the create action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to create a `post` that will contain it's `forum_id` that the form resides in. I need both ID to save in the object to achieve that.

I initialize a new `@post` in the `new` action using `@post = Forum.find(params[:forum_id]).posts.build`
Which will spit out unsaved instance of a post containing it the `forum_id` just as intended.

I then fill out my form here:

```
<%= form_for @post, :url => {:controller => "posts", :action => "create"} do |f| %>
  <% if @post.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this post from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %>
    <%= f.text_field :title, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description %>
    <%= f.text_area :description, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

And when I click the submit button and inspect `post_params` with byebug after the line `@post = Post.new(post_params)` in the `create` action, only the `:title` and `:description` come through. The `forum_id` is lost in between actions and I cannot the save `@post` without it. I have `:forum_id` whitelisted in my `post_params` but it's not coming through. I would think that if an instance of `post` is created in the `new` action with a `forum_id` that it should persist into the `create` action inside `post_params` but something is wrong here.  Here is the relevant information that might help with my issue.

My model's relationships:

```
# User model
has_many :forums
has_many :posts

# Forum model
belongs_to :user
has_many :posts

# Post model
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :forum

# post_controller
def new
  @post = Forum.find(params[:forum_id]).posts.build
end
```

Post Controller

```
def create
  @post = Post.new(post_params)
  respond_to do |format|
    if @post.save
      format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @post }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

...
 # Rest of actions
...
def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :description, :forum_id, :user_id)
  end
end
```

Comment: what does your routes look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Form doesn't submit forum_id because it doesn't exist on there

I think you need to add this to that form

```
<%= f.hidden_field :forum_id %>
```

Comment: I could do that, however. It exists on right after I create it using `.build` in the `new` action here:

#<Post id: nil, title: nil, description: nil, user_id: nil, forum_id: 1, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>

Why would I have to place it with a `hidden_field` if `.build` is supposed to accomplish that? Am I not thinking correctly about it?

Comment: Because in your parameters you allow `forum_id` but you're not supplying it when posting. Therefore, the value is `nil`.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I did some experimenting and reading and yes, this is correct. I am marking it as such. Thank you for your help.